# Date Format Matlab

Tags: matlab, date, formatting, date-formatting

I am having an error my date format is

```
DateSTr{1} {'30/07/2017 12:00:00'}    Datestr{2}  {'31/07/2017'}
```

The format of `DateStr{2}` is wrong. How can I make sure it is at the good format?

```
Error using datenum (line 190)
DATENUM failed.

Error in ModemJobAnalysis/GetReceptionSuccessProbability>GetEventMask (line 107)
Dates=[datenum(DateStr{1},date_format),datenum(DateStr{2},date_format)];

Caused by:
    Error using dtstr2dtnummx
    Failed to convert from text to date number.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same `date_format` for both strings, you should change your format accordingly the input string as in example below:

If in your input string you have `30/07/2017 12:00:00`, your `date_format` should be `'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS'`:

```
>> datenum('30/07/2017 12:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS')

ans =

   7.3691e+05
```

But when you don't use time (like your second string `31/07/2017`) , you should change your format to `'dd/mm/yyyy'`:

```
>> datenum('31/07/2017','dd/mm/yyyy')

ans =

      736907
```

Therefore, to correct your code try something like:

```
Dates=[datenum(DateStr{1},'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS'),datenum(DateStr{2},'dd/mm/yyyy')];
```

---

**EDIT**

You can verify the size of your string to see if it contains the time using `length(DateSTr{1})` which gives 10 to `31/07/2017` and 19 to `30/07/2017 12:00:00`.

Therefore, to adjust all your strings, just verify its size, and add the time marker at the end, if necessary, such as:

```
DateSTr = {'30/07/2017 12:00:00', '31/07/2017'}

for k=1:length(DateSTr)
    if length(DateSTr{k}) < 19    % If date string is not complete 
        DateSTr{k} = strcat(DateSTr{k},' 00:00:00') % Concatenate time to correct the string
    end
end
```

Which gives, respectively, input and output:

```
DateSTr =

  1×2 cell array

    {'30/07/2017 12:00:00'}    {'31/07/2017'}


DateSTr =

  1×2 cell array

    {'30/07/2017 12:00:00'}    {'31/07/2017 00:00:00'}
```

Comment: Actually I only have one format (with the seconds) but on some of my files, in some dates the seconds do not appear. Therefore I want to make sure there are all at the same format

Comment: @Paul is it only missing seconds you want to handle, or do you want to handle any truncation?

Comment: @Paul Please, look at my answer now. I edited it, I think it might help you.